# Printing Canvas to image silverlight

Tags: silverlight, printing, bitmap, raster

I have scuccesfully added canvas to bitmap using WritebleBitmap class and then trying to use the bitmap to save image on client system through SaveFileDilogue. I am  using the method of FluxJpegCore image encoding where we use raster arrays to generate image pixel-wise.
Below is the part of the code which does the job.

```
        byte[][,] raster = new byte[bands][,];

        for (int i = 0; i < bands; i++)
        {
            raster[i] = new byte[width, height];
        }

        for (int row = 0; row < height; row++)
        {
            for (int column = 0; column < width; column++)
            {
                int pixel = bitmap.Pixels[width * row + column];
                raster[0][column, row] = (byte)(pixel >> 16);
                raster[1][column, row] = (byte)(pixel >> 8);
                raster[2][column, row] = (byte)pixel;
            }
        }
```

All goes fine with image saving, however when i zoom the image and then print it, the code fails at the line "raster[i] = new byte[width, height];". System out of memory error is raised. Can anyone help me to find the solution on this?

Comment: When it fails what are the values of width and height?

Comment: Values are width = "3687" and Height = "44278"

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure there is a solution to be had.  You have 3 arrays that each need a contiguous 163MB block of memory.  The problem will be that the process does not have 3 such address blocks available that are that size.

Bear in mind also that the `bitmap.Pixels` will be an array 653MB big.

Your only real hope(s) would be to

1. Use the app OOB, hopefully VM fragmentation would be limited and allow such very large arrays to be allocated.
2. If FluxJpegCore can use `Stream` instead of a byte array and does so effeciently (still a lot of work for you to do there)
3. Move up to Silverlight 5 and host your app in a 64 bit browser instance.

Comment: Hi Anthony. Thanks for the help! Is there any other alternative available to print large images? I have scrollviewer with large image content on it. I convert it to stackpanel and then generate writeablebitmap from the same. some times this process only gives out of memory errors.

Answer (score 0):

Going with @AnthonyWJones I'm pretty sure width or height is something like double.NAN. Make sure you place a check to see is width and height is a real number. Also check that your array does not a lot for more than possible within Silverlight

Comment: No they are not NAN in any case